# How do i hide the food which hit the monkey

Tags: lua, coronasdk

ok so i want that every time a certain food hit the monkey, the certain food disappears

```
local objects = {
"banana", 
"grape", 
"pineapple", 
"strawberry",
"watermelon", 

}
 local function spawnObject()
    local objIdx = mRandom(#objects)
    local objName = objects[objIdx]
    local object = display.newImage( "images/fruit_" .. objName .. "_100.png" )
    object.x = mRandom(screenLeft+30, screenRight-30)
    object.y = screenTop
    object.rotation = mRandom(-15, 15)
    if objIdx < 4 then
        object.type = "food"
    else it
        object.type = "other"
    end
    physics.addBody(object, "dynamic")
    grassfront320w:toFront()
```

**I tried adding this line of code but it gives a error**

```
 local function monkeyCollision( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if event.target.type == "monkey" and event.other.type == "food" then
            print( "chomp!" )
            Objects.alpha = 0
```

Comment: Second part is incomplete, but from what I see instead of Objects.alpha you need to write event.other.alpha

Answer (score 0):

```
local function monkeyCollision( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if event.target.type == "monkey" and event.other.type == "food" then
            print( "chomp!" )
            event.other.alpha = 0
```